# Boot Debian with Android

Tags: android, debian

I want to boot Debian when Android machine starts up.

I installed the debian using Debian kit for Android
http://sven-ola.dyndns.org/repo/debian-kit-en.html

Everything fine, but I have to input the command "deb" to start up the debian.

Could you tell me how to mount the debian when android starts up?

Comment: Did you get some result in that quest?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Script Manager (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=os.tools.scriptmanager) to run  script with the following contents at boot:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
deb s
```

Use your own parameters to "deb" to launch whatever service you need. In this case I've started the ssh server.